# Comparing two normal distributions with different mean

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If I have two normal distributions $\mathcal{N}_1(\mu_1 = 8, \sigma^2 = 2)$ and $\mathcal{N}_2(\mu_2 = 10, \sigma^2 = 2)$, how do I turn these into the **standard** normal distribution, so I can easily calculate relations between the two. Do I use the same mean on both $Y_1 = \dfrac{X_1-\mu_1}{\sigma}$, $Y_2 = \dfrac{X_2-\mu_1}{\sigma}$ or two different means $Y_1 = \dfrac{X_1-\mu_1}{\sigma}$, $Y_2 = \dfrac{X_2-\mu_2}{\sigma}$ on the transform?

Comment: Using the rules of linearity of expectations, what is $\mathbb{E}[\frac{X_2 - \mu_1}{\sigma}]$?

Comment: @MichaelChirico 1, while $\mathrm{E}[\frac{X_2-\mu_2}{\sigma}] = 0$, which makes comparisons useless. So it seems to be $X_2-\mu_1$, so why is one allowed to make such a choice?

Comment: @Max That doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Yes, it does. Your question is "I have two nonstandard normals. How do turn them into standard ones?" The result is proved in that question.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.. you have two normal distributions and what to turn them into standard normal – what does it matter how many distributions you have or which mean/variance they have? The procedure for standardizing a Normal distribution is always the same..

Comment: @SlugPue if I both turn them into the same standard normal distribution, I can no longer tell the difference between the two; I need the means to be distinct. So the question is flawed; it's not possible to turn both into the SND at the same time -- the other one will have its mean shifted. The question is really about how this shift is calculated, but I phrased it awkwardly ...